# flipping array element data in C using nested loops

Tags: c, arrays, nested-loops

How can I flip the element of an array using a nested loops as shown below ?

```
-1 -2 -3                3  2  1
 4  5  6   -------->    4  5  6 
 1  2  3               -3 -2 -1
```

Many thanks ^_^

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: This is not a "Please do my homework" service. The essence of homework is that you learn something. So I suggest you start learning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly a write my code request, not a question. Please read [Ask] page first. :)

Comment: its not about "to write my code ", u can help with hints and tips if u wish.

Comment: For example, what happens when 5 × 5?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you need something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   3

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N][N] =
    {
        { -1, -2, -3 },
        {  4,  5,  6 },
        {  1,  2,  3 }
    };      

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%2d ", a[i][j] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N / 2; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            int tmp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j];
            a[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%2d ", a[i][j] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
-1 -2 -3 
 4  5  6 
 1  2  3 

 3  2  1 
 4  5  6 
-3 -2 -1
```

Comment: that is exactly what I'm looking for :) 
thank you ^_^